# How get rid from redirect while using NGINX

Tags: amazon-web-services, web-services, nginx, nginx-config

I've always used Apache as my web server, but i now have to use NGINX for other reasons. This is now running on a AWS Linux AMI.
This is my first time playing around I have managed to get a blank config working but when i add in my rules i converted from .htaccess i keep getting the site going into a redirect. Not sure if its my config or not. Also, im not sure if you need a seperate one for 443?

```
server {
  listen 80;
  server_name sitename.co.uk www.sitename.co.uk;
  root /var/www/html/Project;

  location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;

    if (!-e $request_filename){
      rewrite ^/([^\.]+)$ /$1.php break;
    }
    if ($http_host ~* "^sitename\.co.uk"){
      rewrite ^(.*)$ https://sitename.co.uk/$1 redirect;
    }
    if (!-e $request_filename){
      rewrite ^(.*)$ /index.php break;
    }
    if (!-e $request_filename){
      rewrite ^(.*)$ /index.php break;
    }
  }

access_log /var/log/nginx/sitename.access.log;
error_log /var/log/nginx/sitename.co.uk.error.log;
}
```

Any help would be great.

Comment: I suspect it's because of the second `if` block - the rewrite and redirect. This looks like it's for redirecting from http to https, and isn't going to work in that context.

Answer (score 1):

This is probably due to this part causing an infinite loop:

```
if ($http_host ~* "^sitename\.co.uk"){
  rewrite ^(.*)$ https://sitename.co.uk/$1 redirect;
}
```

This seems like it could have been for redirecting http to https. The correct way to achieve this in nginx is to use two separate server blocks. One listening on 443(https) and configured with ssl, and the other listening on 80(http) with contents that looks like this:

```
server {
 listen 80;
 server_name sitename.co.uk www.sitename.co.uk;
 return 301 https://sitename.co.uk$request_uri;
}
```

There are many tutorials elsewhere on the web for nginx config, so I won't go into further detail. Hopefully this helps solve your immediate issues. :)

Comment: Thank you for that, i'll give this a try. I dont need to write a 443 block as Cloudflare handles my HTTPS and SSL.